# Why `$graphLookup`'s `connectFromField` field does not accept an array?

Tags: mongodb

`connectFromField` of `$graphLookup` is documented to take in an array: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

> Field name whose value $graphLookup uses to recursively match against the connectToField of other documents in the collection. If the value is an array, each element is individually followed through the traversal process.

But on every version of MongoDB I have tried it fails with this error when provided an array of strings:

```
Error:
Uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "expected string as argument for connectFromField, found: [ \"name\", \"id\" ]",
    "code" : 40103,
    "codeName" : "Location40103"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:583:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:673:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1012:12
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1
```

Example query:

```js
db.getCollection('sensor_data').aggregate([{$graphLookup: {
    from: 'sensor_data',
    startWith: 'name',
    connectFromField: ['name', 'id'],
    connectToField: 'value',
    as: 'children'
}}])
```

Am I doing something wrong or does `connectFromField` value simply doesn't accept an array?

Comment: Your example show an array being assigned to `connectFromField` not `connectToField`.
?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Yes, sorry I messed up the question. It should be `connectFromField` that should be accepting arrays but is not.

Answer (score 0):

The "value" being referred to is the value for the specified field in the document(s) being traversed. You cannot specify multiple field names.